# Google Scripts " e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW' " functionality - Reading when a new row is inserted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to get my Google sheet to perform certain functions only when a new row is added. After some research I found the `.changeType` function which seems to work, but I'm having trouble then getting more functions to run based on that condition.

As you can see in my code, I'm using the `.changeType` function within an if statement.

The if statement appears to work, and it works up until the ui alert - which also works. However, none of the code below it does.

The weird part is that the same code works if I take it outside of the if function.

I'm having a lot of trouble debugging this as the Google Scripts debug tool thinks `if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW')` is an incorrect line of code, but I don't feel it is as it does actually run correctly in the Google sheet. I think this is something to do with the on change trigger functionality.

Perhaps it's the rest of my code that's incorrect, but I can't understand why it works when it's not within that if statement.

What I'm trying to do is to get the row that's just been added, by getting the active range of cells. Then, find the range of cells from immediately below that cell right to the last populated cell in the whole sheet. Those cells should then move with the `.moveTo` function.

Can anyone explain what's going wrong here? it's been impossible to debug so far!

Code is below:

```
function moveUpRows(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW')
  {
    ui.alert("new row added!");
    var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var belowActiveRange = range.offset(1, 0);
    var rangeMovingUp = sheet.getRange("L"+belowActiveRange.getRow()+":S"+sheet.getLastRow())
    rangeMovingUp.moveTo(rangeMovingUp.offset(-1, 0));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try use event data: `var range = e.range;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you insert a new row - this will lead to an undefined active range notation

In fact, `Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());` will log `#REF!`

You can work around this limitation by defining:

```
...
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
var row = range.getLastRow();
var belowActiveRange = sheet.getRange(row+1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
...
```