# get Row number of an inserted row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I had a spreadsheet and I want to know when the user insert a row, that's why I created the onChange event on my script project and I can capture the event.changeType == INSERT_ROW, but I can not get the row number that was inserted as I can do in a onEdit trigger e.range.getRow()

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Related: [Google Scripts “ e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW' ” functionality - Reading when a new row is inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59881705/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  if(e.changeType=="INSERT_ROW") {
    const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    const rg=sh.getActiveRange();
    ss.toast("sheet: " + sh.getName() + " - row: " + rg.getRow());
  }
}
```

[Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)